# Getting a Uncaught (in promise)TypeError: transactions.reduce is not a function on deployed app heroku but not locally npm start wondering why that is

Tags: javascript

Here's the code:

```js
function populateTotal() {
  // reduce transaction amounts to a single total value
  let total = transactions.reduce((total, t) => {
    return total + parseInt(t.value);
  }, 0);

  let totalEl = document.querySelector("#total");
  totalEl.textContent = total;
}
```

Getting this error on the deployed app:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: transactions.reduce is not a function;

Comment: Where is `transactions` defined?

Comment: reduce doesnt exist on transactions. Are you sure you are using the correct var? or class? is transactions undefined?

Comment: @DerekLawrence if transactions was undefined, there would be a different error message ("Cannot read property ... Of undefined")

Comment: the variable `transactions` needs to be an array to use the `Array.reduce()` method

Comment: With the current information, the only thing we can say, is that `transactions` is not an array.

Comment: transactions is define outside the function. It's written like this : var transactions = [];